# CasperJS getting innerHTML of element by class

Tags: javascript, xpath, web-scraping, casperjs

I'm new to CasperJS and I'm having a few issues getting the innerHTML out of `<p class="city">Data I Need</p>`

I have tried a few things, but nothing seems to get it.

```js
var city_name= casper.evaluate(".//*[@class='city_name']", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
var friend_username = city_name.innerHTML;
```

and

```js
var city_name = this.evaluate(function() {
    return document.querySelector(".//*[@class='city_name']").innerHtml;
});
```

Answer (score 8):

CasperJS works by default with CSS selectors:

```js
var city_name = casper.evaluate(function() {
    return document.querySelector(".city_name").innerHTML;
});
```

Note that the property is `innerHTML` not `innerHtml`. Also note that `casper.evaluate()` is the interface to the page context and has nothing to do with `document.evaluate()`.

You can of course use XPath expressions with a CasperJS utility. Functions like [`casper.getElementInfo()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#getelementinfo) provide you with some additional properties like `html` which is actually the `innerHTML` property on the corresponding DOM element.

```js
var x = require("casper").selectXPath;
...
var city_name = casper.getElementInfo(x(".//*[@class='city_name']")).html;
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, I liked using casper's [getElementInfo()](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#getelementinfo) method:

`casper.getElementInfo('<insert CSS selector>').html`

Or in my case, I wanted the inner text:

`casper.getElementInfo('<insert CSS selector>').text`