# CASPERJS - returned innerHTML is [Object Casper]

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, casperjs

Here is a function which gets called by evaluate():

```
function getScanProgress(){

var resultString = document.querySelector('#p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl03_CPSO_DoctorSearchResults_Label1').innerHTML;
return resultString;

}
```

casper.echo() on the result says it's an [object casper]. However, resultString here should be a String and so passable from the evaluate, correct? What's going wrong here?

Comment: did you try echoing resultString[0] ?

Comment: do a `console.log(resultString)` before you return it and see what it actually is

Comment: Also, this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30486233/casperjs-getting-innerhtml-of-element-by-class

Comment: Yes, you're right it should be a string. Please show the code that produces this output. I think you're using `thenEvaluate` instead of `evaluate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this workaround:

Outside of the DOM context (so, replacing the evaluate()):

```
var prog = this.getHTML('#p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl03_CPSO_DoctorSearchResults_Label1');
```